# Widget never update except when working with debugger or on creation

Tags: android, android-widget

My app widget has a problem: it's never updating. If I set a breakpoint on it on the debugger, I can see that it works but if an user uses it on its device then the refresh doesnt work.

Triggering the refresh manually from the code of the app activity works, and it get refreshed at its creation as well.

Here is the code of my widget:

```
public class WidgetClass extends AppWidgetProvider {


    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {

        for(int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++){
            int currentWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetClass.class);

            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

            //PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);
            final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);


            final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.cancel(pending);
            long interval = 1000*15;

            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),interval, pending);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widgetlayout);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.stationlayout, pending);

            Log.d("Widget Refresh", " Refresh");


            //LISTENER TO OPEN THE APP ON CLICK
            Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clickIntent, 0);
            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetstationlayout, pendingIntent);

            //this refresh the content of the widget
            new AsyncConnectWidget(context,MainActivity.getDB(),MainActivity.sql,null,views,currentWidgetId,appWidgetManager).execute();





        }
    }
}
```

I set it to get refreshed every 30 minutes, which is the minimum interval:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widgetlayout"
    android:minHeight="120dp"
    android:minWidth="280dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

and this is how it is set on the manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
            android:label=".name_of_my_widget"
            android:name=".WidgetClass" >

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad: I wasnt overriding the `OnUpdate` method. I dont why then it was successfully called on the beginning.